# How can I convert console.readline to enum?

Tags: enums, computer-science

I have this enumeration for the days of the week. I have the variable "weekday" to convert it to the enum type. When I want to enter the day by keyboard, I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert the string type to NameDia.CS.Program.Days"

```
**namespace NombreDia_CS
{
    class Program
    {
        enum Dias
        {
            Domingo = 1,
            Lunes,
            Martes,
            Miercoles,
            Jueves,
            Viernes,
            Sabado
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Dias diaSemana;

            Console.WriteLine("Ingresar un valor numerico: ");

            diaSemana = Console.ReadLine(); //the error here
            

            
        }
    }
}**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string so you have to convert it into an integer and then cast it to the enum.

```cs
diaSemana = (Dias)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Or you can do something like this in C# 7+ which will parse the string, and initialize `diaSemana` with the corresponding Dias member

```cs
Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Dias diaSemana);
```

Which is also the same as this

```cs
Dias diaSemana;
Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out diaSemana)
```